# Does asp.Net mvc projects share static Method calls with other sessions of the site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, static-methods

I have a scenario where our Mvc application has two regular classes, with some static methods and some private static variables, that do some logic.

```
public class Foo {
  public Foo() { /*...*/ } 
  public static string Bar(int a, string b) {
    //...
  }
}

public class Boo {
  public Boo () { /*...*/ } 
  public static string Bies(int a, string b) {
    //...
  }
}
```

The reason for making these things static is so we can call the methods like

```
public class MainPageController : Controller
  public ActionResult Index() {
    var test = Foo.Bar(1,"bla 1");
    // ...
  }
  public ActionResult SomeMethodCalledByAjax(int a, string b) {
    var test = Foo.Bar(a, b);
    // ...
  }
}

public class SomeOtherPageController : Controller
  public ActionResult Index() {
    var test = Foo.Bar(2,"bla 2");
    // ...
  }
}
```

from anywhere in the c# code. Many Controllers and controller methods need to have access to this class, but per user instance. So User A should have a different experience than User B, but the convenience of the Static method call as shown above.

So my question is, as in the title: would the example `Foo.Bar()` method be callable from the wrong session.
By session I mean User on computer 1 located in one city, calls the method and affects results for User on computer 2 in a different city.

I ask because with Static classes in mvc, you will definitely experience this issue. But if you have an ordinary instanced class, with static methods in it, would the same effect happen?

I google searched and got no answers. (lately google doesn't seem to give very good results).

We experienced an error from our customers where the logged behavior shows the conditions for One particular customer logged in, but executed code that should be only avaliable for another customer. The code is simply

```
if(someSpecificCondition.Identity == "Example1")
  Foo.Bar();

else if(someSpecificCondition.Identity == "Example2")
  Boo.Bies();
```

Our logs show that the customer executed `Foo.Bar()`, but Identity of that customer is "Example2" and should have gone into `Boo.Bies()` instead.
This is overly simplified and our logic and debugging confirms with 100% certainty that its not a coding error.
Either the session completely exploded and failed many calls (and logs do overflow that day). OR the static nature of both Foo and Boo simply got shared by multiple users and coincidentally created chaos for the other users.
As I mentioned earlier, we did have issues with static classes before. Those issues were fixed since.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well yes => [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) static members are only created once, no matter the amount of instantiated classes. Seems like a fundamental coding flaw and I'd rather go/rebuild this part based on injection.

Comment: So reading that article, the static member inside a non-static class, is shared amongst all instances of that class. But it does not specify if those static members are shared amongst multiple session of that application.

Comment: Why should they be different for sessions? Sessions do not create new processes that would scope their own static stuff (assuming that you host the applicatoin via IIS with in process sessions).

Comment: So what you are saying is that, the static members in an instanced class, lives in the IIS, and therefore could potentially misused across my users (from different computers)?

Comment: Yes. Controllers that call your static methods/properties are backend code which lives inside the IIS. I suggest having a read at (https://stackify.com/w3wp-exe-iis-worker-process/)[https://stackify.com/w3wp-exe-iis-worker-process/] so you can get a better grasp at how IIS handles requests and hosts your application.